# Using jsonpatch to create new path

Tags: json, node.js, json-patch

I'm trying to use jsonpatch to create new path in a mongoose document, but I can't make it work.

The page oficial page [enter link description here](http://jsonpatch.com/) says that I can add new values to a path like this,

```
{op: add, path:/mypath, value: 'new value'}
```

But what I want is to add new path with new values. I've try passing a variable to the path like this:

```
var valuesItem = [{
            op: 'add',
            path: '/' + data,
            value: 'data'
        }];
```

But that don't work.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what you're expecting the input to be and what you'd expect the patched output to look like?

Comment: Well , I have two inputs on the client side , with them I want to build an object and send them to the database via patch to be  added to a document according to an id . I'm using Mongoose database , but I don't know if  necessarily there have to be a model created to have access to the path patch that have to be created.

Thank you very much for your answer. regards

Comment: Did you get this sorted?  The question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Yes the problem was in the api and mongoose, aperently mongoose add to a document some extra data so I had to change the way to update the data in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to change the way that it was updated the data in the database, like this:

```
value = value.toObject();
var patches = request.payload;
jsonpatch.apply(value, patches);

      Value.update({ _id: request.params.id }, value, { overwrite: true }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          reply(err);
        } else {
         ...code...
        }
```